# Use of 'there is' at the end of sentences

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, relative-clauses

Couple of days ago I came across to this sentence:

> I am the most vile man there is.

I get the overall meaning of the sentence but can't figure out why 'there is' used at the end. It has sth to do with relative clause?

Comment: It's a relative clause with "that" omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I am the most vile man there is".

*there is* there means: *that exists*.

"I am the most vile man that exists". [in the world]

If I say: This is the prettiest flower *that exists*. Is that clear?

That idea can also be expressed with "there is".

This is the prettiest flower *there is*.